# Is it possible to modify a WeChat profile pic through code?

Tags: wechat, tencent

I wanted to try writing code to modify my own WeChat profile pic.

However, I couldn't find the documentation regarding profile pictures for WeChat. As such, it could be impossible for all I know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's no problem to "reproduce". I'm trying to create a new tool.